# Adding an attribute to method parameter with Roslyn codefix

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm making an analyzer with Roslyn to add the postsharp [NotNull] attribute to method parameters.

```
private async Task<Document> MakeNotNullAsync(Document document, MethodDeclarationSyntax method, CancellationToken cancellationToken, string paramName)
    {

        var parameters = method.ChildNodes().OfType<ParameterListSyntax>().First();
        var param = parameters.ChildNodes().OfType<ParameterSyntax>().First() as SyntaxNode;



        NameSyntax name = SyntaxFactory.ParseName("NotNull");
        AttributeSyntax attribute = SyntaxFactory.Attribute(name, null);
        Collection<AttributeSyntax> list = new Collection<AttributeSyntax>();
        list.Add(attribute);
        var separatedlist = SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(list);
        var newLiteral = SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(separatedlist);
        Collection<SyntaxNode> synlist = new Collection<SyntaxNode>();
        synlist.Add(newLiteral);

        var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
        var newRoot = root.InsertNodesBefore(param, synlist);
        var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
        return newDocument;
```

Here is what I have so far (and there is definitely an easier way to do this) but I am getting a 'System.InvalidCastException' when it tries to do root.InsertNodesBefore(). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's the message and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

I usually find it much easier to work with `ReplaceNode`. In your case, you just have to replace `param` with one that has the new attribute (via `WithAttributeLists`):

```
var attribute = SyntaxFactory.AttributeList(
    SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList<AttributeSyntax>(
        SyntaxFactory.Attribute(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName("NotNull"), null)));
var newParam = param.WithAttributeLists(param.AttributeLists.Add(attribute));

var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync();
var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(param, newParam);    
var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
return newDocument;
```

Note, that this also handles the case where the `param` has existing attributes.